# RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 1031]' is invalid for input of size 900

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to build a CNN but I get this error:

```
shape '[-1, 1031]' is invalid for input of size 900
```

My code is below:

```
class CPillModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(CPillModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim) 
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)  
        self.act4 = Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        
       ....
       ....
       return x

# instantiate ANN
input_dim = 1031
hidden_dim = 150 
output_dim = 10

# Create ANN
model = CPillModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim)

# Cross Entropy Loss 
error = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()


# SGD Optimizer
learning_rate = 0.02
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


# ANN model training
count = 0
loss_list = []
iteration_list = []
accuracy_list = []      
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
# enumerate mini batches
    for i, (data_a, data_b) in enumerate(train_loader):
        train = Variable(data_a.view(-1, 1031))
        labels = Variable(data_b)
        # clear the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # compute the model output
        outputs = model(data_a)
        # calculate loss
        loss = error(outputs, data_b)
        # credit assignment
        loss.backward()
        # update model weights
        optimizer.step()
        count += 1
```

I think the issue I have is with my train variable line: `train = Variable(data_a.view(-1, 1031))`

I have 1031 rows of features training data but they are not being converted.

Do I split these 1031 data points into a format such as: a x b to work?

Would data reshape work?

The print out of data_a is: `data_a is torch.Size([100, 9]`

Comment: "I have 1031 rows of features training data" the error message disagreed with you on this. Print the shape of `data_a` before that line.

Comment: data_a is torch.Size([100, 9])

Comment: Well, there's no way `[100, 9]` will be reshaped to `[-1, 1031]`. What makes you say you have `1031` features?

Comment: The size of my dataset are:`FeaturesTrain dataset:  torch.Size([1031, 9])
TargetsTrain dataset:  torch.Size([1031])
FeaturesTest dataset:  torch.Size([442, 9])
TargetsTest:  torch.Size([442])`.                                                                                                          That is why I have used 1031. How can I get it to work?

Comment: Well there you have it. The **number of features is `9` not `1031`**. You'd have to change a number of things to "get it to work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the number of features is `9` not `1031`, so you would have to change `input_dim` to `9`.

I would also suggest you reduce the value of `hidden_dim`.

You would also change this line `train = Variable(data_a.view(-1, 1031))` to `train = Variable(data_a)` as there is no need for `data_a` to be reshaped.

I don't know what's inside the `forward` method so I guess that's all you need to change.